# Angular $watch not triggering for array changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm attempting to trigger a $watch after a timeout in angular:

**My Controller**

```
.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.chickens = ["Jim", "Joe", "Fred"];
    $scope.chickens.push("Steve");

    setTimeout(function () {
        $scope.chickens.push("Larry");
        $scope.$apply();
    }, 500);
}])
```

Then the $watch is wired up in my directive's link function:

**My Directive Link**

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch('chickens', function (newChickens, oldChickens) {
        $(element).html('');
        newChickens.forEach(function (chicken) {
            $(element).append($('<li/>', {
                'text': chicken
            }));
        });
    });
}
```

The $watch only seems to fire once with the first four elements, it never fires after the fifth is added. I tried adding the `$scope.$apply()` there to apply the changes. Doesn't seem to be working.

Here's the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9XFb8/3/) for the example. I'd appreciate any help in the situation. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your directive like so:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch('chickens', function (newChickens, oldChickens) {
        $(element).html('');
        newChickens.forEach(function (chicken) {
            $(element).append($('<li/>', {
                'text': chicken
            }));
        });
    }, true);
}
```

The 3rd parameter (`objectEquality`) will make the watch check the whole contents of the array. Specifically it will use `angular.equals` to check the equality of the new and old array:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.equals

Comment: Ah there it is! Makes sense. Wouldn't want to do that all the time for performance purposes. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, it will have a negative impact on performance. Especially if the  array is large.